# posting to fictional character facebook wall

Tags: ios, facebook, fbconnect

Hello fellow developers,

I am looking for a solution regarging Facebook Connect.

We developed a iOS game where we have a fictional character as protagonist who also has a public Facebook profile.

The game is running very good. Now we want to generate some traffic on his Facebook profile. Therefor we're looking for an option to post game results out of the application to the characters public profile in Facebook. We do NOT want to post messages on the user's wall.

Is this a case where we can deal with FB-Connect?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to prompt the user for publish_stream extended permission and post to /pageId/feed

Answer (score 1):

> You can create a post on behalf of the user by issuing an HTTP POST
>   request to PROFILE_ID/feed with the publish_stream permissions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts